# How can I extract the last 2 characers from a string in SPSS using Python?

Tags: python, string, character, extract, spss

What I'm trying to accomplish is extracting the last 2 characters from a string variable that can have text of different lengths, and placed them in a new variable. I know how to do it with SPSS syntax but it is my understanding that it's much more simpler with Python code. My problem is that I don't even know where to begin to look so any help would be much appreciated.

Just to make it clear, let's say I have a variable called "Var01" and for one of the cases the text is "Box12" and I want the "12" in a new variable called "Var02".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pretty simple SPSS syntax, don't need to go into python for that:

```
compute var02=char.substr(var01,char.length(var01)-1).
```

Comment: Thanks for that but as I stated in my post, I know how to do it with SPSS syntax but I would still like to know how to do it with python. This is because I would need a starting point in how python combines with spss.

Comment: @EdwardVarga  got it - I have little use for Python in SPSS myself so you'll have to wait for another answer. On the other hand maybe [this could get you started](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-python-string-tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

```
char = 'character'
new_variable = char[-2:])
output: er
or
text = 'last two characters'
text[-2:]
output : rs
```

Comment: Thanks for that but what I actually need is the python code that works with SPSS.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the tour, and [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)?

Comment: This answer does not answer the OP's question; in my opinion, this answer misses a critical point of the question: do it in SPSS environment.